# How to solve great expectations "MetricResolutionError: Cannot compile Column object until its 'name' is assigned." Error?

Tags: python, great-expectations

I am trying to use great expectations.
The function I want to use is `expect_compound_columns_to_be_unique`.
This is the code (main code - template):

```
import datetime

import pandas as pd

import great_expectations as ge
import great_expectations.jupyter_ux
from great_expectations.core.batch import BatchRequest
from great_expectations.checkpoint import SimpleCheckpoint
from great_expectations.exceptions import DataContextError

context = ge.data_context.DataContext()

# Note that if you modify this batch request, you may save the new version as a .json file
#  to pass in later via the --batch-request option
batch_request = {'datasource_name': 'impala_okh', 'data_connector_name': 'default_inferred_data_connector_name', 'data_asset_name': 'okh.okh_forecast_prod', 'limit': 1000}


# Feel free to change the name of your suite here. Renaming this will not remove the other one.
expectation_suite_name = "okh_forecast_prod"
try:
    suite = context.get_expectation_suite(expectation_suite_name=expectation_suite_name)
    print(f'Loaded ExpectationSuite "{suite.expectation_suite_name}" containing {len(suite.expectations)} expectations.')
except DataContextError:
    suite = context.create_expectation_suite(expectation_suite_name=expectation_suite_name)
    print(f'Created ExpectationSuite "{suite.expectation_suite_name}".')


validator = context.get_validator(
    batch_request=BatchRequest(**batch_request),
    expectation_suite_name=expectation_suite_name
)
column_names = [f'"{column_name}"' for column_name in validator.columns()]
print(f"Columns: {', '.join(column_names)}.")
validator.head(n_rows=5, fetch_all=False)
```

Using this code calling

```
validator.expect_compound_columns_to_be_unique(['column1', 'column2'])
```

produces the following error:

> MetricResolutionError: Cannot compile Column object until its 'name' is assigned.

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

By writing: `validator.expect_compound_columns_to_be_unique(['column1', 'column2'])` you are checking if the tuples made of elements from `'column1'` and `'column2'` are unique.

From the error you are getting it seems like `'column1'` and `'column2'` are not defined in your data. You should try validating on the *actual* names of the columns in your data: since the data you are providing through the `batch_request` only contains the columns `'datasource_name'`, `'data_connector_name'`, `'data_asset_name'` and `'limit'`, then you should validate on a subset of these columns.

For example:
`validator.expect_compound_columns_to_be_unique(['datasource_name', 'data_connector_name'])`.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, seems that you are using double quotes around the column names when printing them in the column_names list:

```
column_names = [f'"{column_name}"' for column_name in validator.columns()]
```

but, when calling `validator.expect_compound_columns_to_be_unique(['column1', 'column2'])`, you should pass the column names without double quotes:

```
validator.expect_compound_columns_to_be_unique(['column1', 'column2'])
```

I would try modifying the column_names generation part to remove the double quotes like:

```
column_names = [column_name for column_name in validator.columns()]
```

Code will be:

```
batch_request = {'datasource_name': 'impala_okh', 'data_connector_name': 'default_inferred_data_connector_name', 'data_asset_name': 'okh.okh_forecast_prod', 'limit': 1000}

expectation_suite_name = "okh_forecast_prod"
try:
    suite = context.get_expectation_suite(expectation_suite_name=expectation_suite_name)
    print(f'Loaded ExpectationSuite "{suite.expectation_suite_name}" containing {len(suite.expectations)} expectations.')
except DataContextError:
    suite = context.create_expectation_suite(expectation_suite_name=expectation_suite_name)
    print(f'Created ExpectationSuite "{suite.expectation_suite_name}".')

validator = context.get_validator(
    batch_request=BatchRequest(**batch_request),
    expectation_suite_name=expectation_suite_name
)
column_names = [column_name for column_name in validator.columns()]
print(f"Columns: {', '.join(column_names)}.")
validator.head(n_rows=5, fetch_all=False)

validator.expect_compound_columns_to_be_unique(['column1', 'column2'])
```